# QPixmap causes memory leak?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qt5, qpixmap

I stream MJPEG from server and update QLabel's QPixmap every time a valid frame received. Memory usage swells in time and I cannot figure out why. Is this a wrong use of QPixmap?

```
    case StreamState::Streaming: {
        int ind_start_bytes = m_buffer.indexOf("\xff\xd8");
        int ind_end_bytes = m_buffer.indexOf("\xff\xd9");
        if(ind_start_bytes != -1 && ind_end_bytes != -1) {
            if(ind_start_bytes < ind_end_bytes){
                QByteArray image_data = m_buffer.mid(ind_start_bytes, ind_end_bytes + 2);
                m_buffer = m_buffer.mid(ind_end_bytes+2);
                QPixmap pmap;
                if(pmap.loadFromData(image_data, "JPEG")) {
                    setPixmap(pmap.scaled(pmap.size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the [github link](https://github.com/grizzlei/qt-mjpeg-streamer) for full code. `mjpegstreamer.cpp` for related code.

Comment: Before I was using a member variable `m_pixmap`, and updated it every time a frame received. But for some reason it did not work in Qt4 (image was updating only once) and I decided to create a local QPixmap every time I need one.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem in this code your memory leak is probably elsewhere

Comment: I guess I found the problem. m_buffer is not being consumed fast enough and it's swelling. Thanks for your effort though! @AlanBirtles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the m_buffer that is swelling. The code i posted consumes frames with fifo logic. So I replaced

```
int ind_start_bytes = m_buffer.indexOf("\xff\xd8");
int ind_end_bytes = m_buffer.indexOf("\xff\xd9");
```

with

```
int ind_start_bytes = m_buffer.lastIndexOf("\xff\xd8");
int ind_end_bytes = m_buffer.lastIndexOf("\xff\xd9");
```

If by any chance more than one frames exist in the `m_buffer`, we will be consuming the last one and remove the ones on the left.
Problem seems to be solved now.
This apparently has nothing to do with `QPixmap`.